Run a function and modify a variable defined in website in a Chrome extension
I'm trying to run an existing function defined in a website using JS for a Chrome extension.
Take a look at the code below, where there is a button which when clicked runs the function refreshDisplayCanvas() and edit the variable zoomRate
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'sha256-0sXv48p25RxCUPpL+i/wI+k+w5bolBEFvagppNo+uK4='">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'sha256-TIBrNhJNjc01RI5q77n3kKSSI1zoEfd/PoNTj3pF56w='">
    <title>...</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>...</h1>
    <p id="zoom-rate">Current Zoom Rate: 1</p>
    <button id="zoom-in">Zoom In</button>
    <button id="zoom-out">Zoom Out</button>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

and here is the Javasript code:
let zoomRate = 1
document.getElementById("zoom-in").onclick = () => {
    zoomRate += 0.25;
    document.getElementById("zoom-rate").innerText = "Current Zoom Rate: " + zoomRate;
    refreshDisplayCanvas(); // This function here is the one already defined in the website
}
document.getElementById("zoom-out").onclick = () => {
    zoomRate -= 0.25;
    document.getElementById("zoom-rate").innerText = "Current Zoom Rate: " + zoomRate;
    refreshDisplayCanvas();
}

and lastly, here is the manifest.json file:
{
   "manifest_version": 3,
   "name": "...",
   "version": "1.0",
   "description": "...",
   "action": {
       "default_popup": "index.html"
   },
   "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "declarativeContent"],
   "content_scripts": [
     {
       "js": ["content.js"],
       "matches": ["https://.../*"]
     }
   ],
   "content_security_policy": {     "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'"   }
}

Note that content.js is empty.
I tried to use eval() and Function() to run the code, but the Content Security Policy thing seems to have blocked them.
Are there any solutions?
